# VBA Macro TO Export Splines from catia to text file(.dat)

Tags: vba, export, catia

so I was wondering if i could get some help here. so basically i am trying to find out how to write a dat file that will be able to import splines into `Catia`. These splines when imported are supposed to act like meshes on a structure, that is, picture a meshed structure, but instead of mesh it will be splines on it. so right now i thought to learn a macro that exports a few splines i created on a structure into a text(.dat) file. but i have been having troubles with the macro i have as it asks me to select a spline, but wont allow me to click on the spline in spec tree. The thing is that i have lots of splines and i would like the macro to just select splines automatically without asking and export them..... PLS HELP ME. thanks alot.

So here is the code:

```
   Sub CATMain()

'*** *** Definition Variables
Dim CtrlPoint()
Dim oCoordinates(1)
Dim StartKrit As Integer

'*** Query document type ***
StartKrit = 0
Set oDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
ObjType = TypeName(oDoc)
If ObjType = "PartDocument" Then
DocType = "Part"
StartKrit = 1
ElseIf ObjType = "DrawingDocument" Then
DocType = "Drawing "
StartKrit = 1
End If

If StartKrit = 0 Then
box = MsgBox(" The active document is neither a CATPart still CATDrawing! " + Chr(10) + _
" The macro can not continue and will now exit " + Chr(10) + _
"Please select a CATPart or a CATDrawing and start the macro again!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "incorrect document type")
Exit Sub
End If


'*** Create the * .txt files ***
StorePath = "C: \"
StoreName = "Splinekoordinaten" & Date
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fs.FileExists(StorePath & StoreName & ".txt ") = True Then
box = MsgBox(" file ==> " + StorePath + StoreName + " <== already exists! " + Chr(10) + " Do you want to overwrite the file? ", vbCritical + vbYesNo, "file already exists ")
If box = vbNo Then
box = MsgBox(" The macro is now finished ", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, " the user stops ")
Exit Sub
End If
End If
Set A = fs.CreateTextFile("D:\school\INTERNSHIP\Macro\Newest.txt ", True)
A.WriteLine (" points coordinates of a spline ")
A.WriteLine (" ")
If DocType = " Part " Then
A.WriteLine (" name of CATParts: " & oDoc.Name)
ElseIf DocType = " Drawing " Then
A.WriteLine ("name of CATDrawing:" & oDoc.Name)
End If
A.WriteLine ("")

'*** Readout from the CATDrawing ***
If DocType = "Drawing" Then
Dim otype2D(0)
Dim Selection
Set mysel = oDoc.Selection
mysel.Clear
otype2D(0) = "Spline2D"
mysel.Clear
box = MsgBox(" Please select now the spline ", vbInformation + vbOKCancel, " spline Select ")
If box = vbCancel Then
box = MsgBox(" you have the selection canceled " + Chr(10) + _
" the macro is now finished! ", vbCritical, "abort by user")
If fs.FileExists(StorePath & StoreName & ".txt") = True Then
A.Close
fs.DeleteFile (StorePath & StoreName & ".txt")
End If
Exit Sub
End If
Selection = mysel.SelectElement2(otype2D, "Please select the spline", False)
If Selection = "Normal" Then
oSplineName = mysel.Item(1).Value.Name
Set oSpline = mysel.Item(1).Value
A.WriteLine ("name of the selected spline:" & oSplineName)
A.WriteLine ("")
A.WriteLine ("")
Else
box = MsgBox("you have canceled the selection" + Chr(10) + _
"the macro is now finished! ", vbCritical, " abort by user ")
If fs.FileExists(StorePath & StoreName & " .txt ") = True Then
A.Close
fs.DeleteFile (StorePath & StoreName & " .txt ")
End If
Exit Sub
End If
mysel.Clear

Set QuCtrlP = oSpline.EndPoint
QuCtrlPRaw = QuCtrlP.Name
QuCtrlPSemi = Split(QuCtrlPRaw, ".")
QuCtrlPFin = QuCtrlPSemi(1) - 1
ReDim Preserve CtrlPoint(QuCtrlPFin)
For j = 0 To QuCtrlPFin
Set CtrlPoint(j) = oSpline.GetItem("Ktrl-point." & j + 1)
CtrlPoint(j).GetCoordinates oCoordinates
A.WriteLine ("point" & j + 1 & "X / Y")
A.WriteLine (oCoordinates(0))
A.WriteLine (oCoordinates(1))
A.WriteLine ("")
Next

'*** readout from the CATPart ***
ElseIf DocType = "Part" Then
Dim otype3D(0)
Set mysel = oDoc.Selection
mysel.Clear
otype3D(0) = "Spline2D"
mysel.Clear
box = MsgBox("Please select now the spline", vbInformation + vbOKCancel, "spline Select")
If box = vbCancel Then
box = MsgBox("you have canceled the selection" + Chr(10) + _
"The macro is now finished!", vbCritical, "abort by user")
If fs.FileExists(StorePath & StoreName & ".txt") = True Then
A.Close
fs.DeleteFile (StorePath & StoreName & ".txt ")
End If
Exit Sub
End If
Selection = mysel.SelectElement2(otype3D, " Please select the spline ", False)
If Selection = " Normal " Then
oSplineName = mysel.Item(1).Value.Name
Set oSpline = mysel.Item(1).Value
A.WriteLine ("name of the selected spline:" & oSplineName)
A.WriteLine ("")
A.WriteLine ("")
Else
box = MsgBox("you have canceled the selection" + Chr(10) + _
"The macro is now finished!", vbCritical, "abort by user")
If fs.FileExists(StorePath & StoreName & ".txt") = True Then
A.Close
fs.DeleteFile (StorePath & StoreName & " .txt ")
End If
Exit Sub
End If

mysel.Clear
Set QuCtrlP = oSpline.EndPoint
QuCtrlPRaw = QuCtrlP.Name
QuCtrlPSemi = Split(QuCtrlPRaw, " ")
QuCtrlPFin = QuCtrlPSemi(1) - 1
ReDim Preserve CtrlPoint(QuCtrlPFin)
For j = 0 To QuCtrlPFin
Set CtrlPoint(j) = oSpline.GetItem("Ktrl-point." & j + 1)
CtrlPoint(j).GetCoordinates oCoordinates
A.WriteLine ("point" & j + 1 & "X / Y")
A.WriteLine (oCoordinates(0))
A.WriteLine (oCoordinates(1))
A.WriteLine ("")
Next
End If

'**** Issue Storage Location ****
Ml = "The macro has completed successfully"
M2 = "The * .txt file is saved under the following path:"
M2_ZU_1 = "==>"
M2_ZU_2 = "<== "
M3 = " Are you in the path now oeffnen? "
Title = "memory data"
skin = vbInformation + vbYesNo
query = MsgBox(Ml + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + M2 + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + M2_ZU_1 + StorePath + StoreName + M2_ZU_2 + Chr(10) + Chr(10) + M3, skin, Title)

If query = vbYes Then
ExplorerPath = "C: \ WINDOWS \ explorer.exe"
Explorer = CATIA.SystemService.ExecuteProcessus(ExplorerPath & "" & StorePath)
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectelement2 filter is set for spline2D, are you selected sketch splines or 3d splines?

If you are working with 3d splines like it sounds, you want to use this code:

```
mysel.Clear
otype3D(0) = "HybridShapeSpline"
mysel.Clear
box = MsgBox("Please select now the spline", vbInformation + vbOKCancel, "spline Select")
If box = vbCancel Then
box = MsgBox("you have canceled the selection" + Chr(10) + _
"The macro is now finished!", vbCritical, "abort by user")
If fs.FileExists(StorePath & StoreName & ".txt") = True Then
A.Close
fs.DeleteFile (StorePath & StoreName & ".txt ")
End If
Exit Sub
End If
Selection = mysel.SelectElement2(otype3D, " Please select the spline ", False)
```

You'll find more help on www.coe.org, there is a significant group of CATIA automators there.